# Why was this comment section deleted?

Tags: discussion, comment, deletion

Over the past 24 hours, [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4668495/339790)'s comment section was summarily deleted.  I do **not** understand why.  No moderator left a comment explaining why comments were deleted. Clarification would be most welcome.

Please do note that the most useful comment in this comment section was [littleO](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/40119/littleo)'s, **not** mine.

Comment: @postmortes Well, "transient" comments should be deleted once the information contained in them has been incorporated into the question, not before.  If they are deleted before they add value to the question, then we have a case of **vandalism**. A community of volunteers in which the work of volunteers is often vandalized with impunity is an **un**healthy community.

Comment: @postmortes I am not shouting at anyone. Policies are enforced by *human* moderators. The whole idea of "rule of law" is mostly a fairy tale.

Comment: As only a moderator can help here, maybe it makes more sense to post to the moderator's chat room than to this site.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Good point. However, if the reasons for deletion can be shared on Meta, it would be helpful to have them visible to users other than I.

Comment: I believe that a moderator recently deleted some of my comments also. It is of course possible that they were flagged by someone in the community, but I suspect not in this case. I am concerned that some moderators may have been shifting to a more heavy-handed and unilateral moderation style that is unprecedented on this site.  But when moderator actions are silent and invisible, who can tell?

Comment: Okay, everyone's overreacting.  Maybe someone just accidently clicked delete.

Comment: @DLeftAdjointtoU So here would be the place to own up to such honest mistake. Not doing so only erodes the trust further, which has become a precious commodity on MSE in late years.

Comment: Right now there are two close votes for a lack of context, but under the guidelines for context rewrites any comments of OP may be copied into the main post to complete the context. If the OP made any comments containing context then removing those comments amounts to lowering the quality of the question. The quality of the question is more important than the screen space taken up by comments.

Comment: were there 2 or 3 comments or more? If the no. was few, accidental deletion may be a reason.

Comment: Might not be relevant, but I've had at least one experience like that. I remember commenting something like, "Yeah, you have to edit your work into the original post instead of the comments" on a post that had a half-hearted attempt. I don't know if it got flagged or if a moderator deleted it, but I was never notified about it. The only reason I found out was that I went back to see if the poster edited his query so that I could answer it.

Comment: From my experience, I’m telling you no moderator are going to respond to you. If you ask them more, you will likely get suspended. So be careful while asking things (e.g. to justify/defend there actions) to mods.

Comment: Just to supply a data point of a (perhaps superficially) similar situation, I remember one post where a comment thread was deleted, because the later comments in the thread devolved into a rather uncivil tone and drifted off-topic. The last few comments where probably flagged as "no longer needed" or "unfriendly or unkind", and a moderator dealing with it explained that the right course of action was to remove the entire discussion, because these bad comments were close follow-ups of earlier comments and deleting the bad ones alone would only leave room for similar follow-ups to be generated.

Comment: To be honest I’m surprised at how silent the mods have been. This meta post has been up for three days now and is even in the hot meta posts. Typically, they are the first to comment on hot meta posts. For example, look at the current hot meta post. I guess, mods are immune (aka qualified immunity) to deleting comment without explaining the reasons behind their decision. Perhaps explaining their reasoning is highly confidential and must not be shared with community.

Comment: @user264745 one can be charitable and assume that they were not around over the weekend.

Comment: @ElliotYu how that (the one you described) situation is similar to current situation? At least, we don’t know yet weather OP’s post had an “unfriendly or unkind” comment.

Comment: Comments are ephemeral and temporary, and are often deleted without notice.  In this particular case, (1) automatic flags were raised because there were too many comments, (2) a large number of comments had already been deleted, and (3) many of the remaining comments had been flagged as "no longer necessary". The net result is that, rather than wading through the mess that the comment section there had become, I deleted all of the comments. If something is worth keeping, either discuss it in chat, or edit it into a question or answer.  Do not be surprised when long comments threads are delted.

Comment: @XanderHenderson In your opinion, why comments are considered “ephemeral and temporary”? Is this a policy enforced by Math Stack Exchange? How many of the remaining comments have been flagged as no longer necessary? If, for example, two out of 20 comments under a post are no longer necessary, would you delete all of them? Your action are similar to those of close votes reviewer, who instead of editing a post to make it better, choose to close it because editing is messy. You are aware that new users are unlikely to discuss things in a chat room.

Comment: @user264745 Comments are described this way in the [help center](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment):  "Comments are temporary "Post-It" notes left on a question or answer. They can be upvoted (but not downvoted) and flagged, but do not generate reputation. There's no revision history, and when they are deleted they're gone for good."  Don't put things in the comments if you want them to stick around.

Comment: @XanderHenderson I know you only answered my first question (comments are temporary). Your answer in itself sounds wrong. You have the power to delete comment. One day you may choose to delete all comment, after all “comment are temporary”. You should have reasonably strong ground to delete comment. IMO laziness is not a strong ground.

Comment: @XanderHenderson *"Don't put things in the comments if you want them to stick around"* — So, the only time when commenting is not a potential waste of time is when all the mods are sleeping?  Since the OP may be sleeping or taking classes, it may be the case that the OP will not check his Stack Exchange inbox for some 24 hours or more, and comments may be deleted before the OP has had the time to digest them and incorporate the information contained in them into the question.  Moreover, can one post answers instead of comments?  Of course not, as comment-like answers are deleted.

Comment: @XanderHenderson *"Comments are ephemeral and temporary"* — Yes, I have flagged comments as "no longer needed" at least **902** times.  I assume that most of these were due to the information contained in the comments having been incorporated into the questions / answers, thereby rendering the comments "no longer needed"

Comment: Ah, so I see that editing comments into the question is a way to preserve comments, especially when the question is closed and doesn't allow new answers. And there's revision history to show who said what too.

Comment: @peterwhy Why would I be interested in having comments of mine, which I assume are "ephemeral and temporary", copied into a question, thereby creating a permanent record out of comments that were never written under the assumption that they would be permanent?  Do I understand you correctly?

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo I was just saying that is an option and possibility I learnt from this conversation, for comments that are relevant and worth keeping. I am not sure if I like the idea to “comment in the post body, not in the comments” too.

Comment: The truth is, mod time and attention is a limited resource, and we don't have the bandwidth to go through every comment in a long thread and evaluate it for relevancy. Sometimes good comments get deleted with bad comments. If you feel one of them was really important, just bring it up in the mod office.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo Under the (revised) guidelines for context rewrites and edits, anyone is free to improve a question by editing OP's comments appropriately into the question. What peterwhy is trying to say is that doing this is useful when OP includes context in the comments but not in the main post. Not every comment of OP will be important but editing the question creates a permanent record of all their context. I still disagree with the comment removal, but the incorporation of comments is something I'd like to see done more often.

Comment: @SarveshRavichandranIyer Yes, that is what I usually do.  I improve the question then flag the comments as "no longer needed".  However, when one does not understand the OP because the question lacks clarity, how can one improve the question?  One must wait for the OP to provide clarification.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo Of course, to engage the OP one has to comment. I am assuming that the mod removed some of OP's useful comments as well and in that case I suggest the editing of those comments into the question before the removal of the comments. If the OP made no comments then I'm surprised by the mod action because the comments made by you, littleO etc. would definitely have been needed as prompts that the OP can respond to. They were definitely not "not necessary" at the time of removal in that case.

Comment: @AlexanderGruber The issue I see here is that it *seems* that someone had done some work for the mods by flagging some comments as "no longer necessary". However, this sifting was ignored and *everything* was deleted. So although mod time is a limited resource, surely either deleting just the flagged comments, i.e. trusting the flagger, or trying to engage with the flagger/a commenter to get them to do the work instead (ensure all unneeded comments are flagged, or save some into a question/answer) would have been in general better?

Comment: (A secondary issue is why the default of "delete" when something is unclear? But I guess this is only an issue if these kinds of threads have a small complaint-to-deletion ratio.)

Comment: @user1729 When there is a long conversation with many comments that need deleted, people have a tendency to only flag one or two of them. This isn't ideal, but it's what people do, so we still have to go give it a cursory look. In this case, the comments look like they lack future value to me, frankly, even after further examination.

Comment: Regarding your second comment, one has to consider whether to favor more type 1 errors or more type 2 errors, and I think that varies from mod to mod.

Comment: @AlexanderGruber Thanks for your explanations. I appreciate them.